# Selecting and moving points/polygons from multiple shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-plugins

It seems that QGIS supports only moving one shapefile at a time.

I have installed the MultipleSelection plugin but I receive the following.

> 2022-06-09T13:42:21     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users//AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\MultipleLayerSelection\MultiLayerRectangleSelection.py",
> line 43, in canvasReleaseEvent
> layer.selectByRect(lRect, False)
> TypeError: QgsVectorLayer.selectByRect(): argument 2 has unexpected type 'bool'

Could anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: You are editing two shapefiles at the same time and want to move a polygon from each layer at the same time?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am working with eight different shapefiles containing points, lines and polygons. I need to move all of this data to align to ground control points.

Comment: Maybe you can use Affine Transform processing tool?